# Android's Policy for throwing processes out of memory

Tags: android, native

I have a service in Android which takes a lot of memory and is occasionally removed from running.
What is the rule by which Android decides to remove a process? If so - how can I tell I'm about to stop running due to too much memory consumption? Most of the memory I allocate is allocated in native code.

Answer (score 0):

If some other Application is consuming memory then also service can be terminated.Because there are not enough heap memory to allocate for your Application.To handle this you can handle low memory functions and inform user that Application is running on low memory.Also, while starting your service you can set to restart again.

Cheers.